# Blackberry pressing buttonfield for n seconds

Tags: java, blackberry

I am developing a blackberry app. I want to fire any operation in the same screen when user will press one button and hold it for 2 seconds.

any way

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need to do in very informal pseudoceode:

```
    When (click detected)
        Schedule Timer to execute in 2s.

    When (unclick detected)
        Cancel timer
```

The timer is scheduled when the user first clicks on it. If the user exceeds 2s with the button pressed, then the timer will run. Otherwise, when the button is released before 2s, the timer is cancelled and wont run. Notice that the Timer can also be cancelled if the user releases just at 2s time, or later. In those cases it is not a problem, because if it is cancelled while it is running, it is allowed to complete, and if it is cancelled after having completed, it does nothing.

To detect the click/unclick you have several choices. You can extend from your button class and override [`touchEvent`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#touchEvent%28net.rim.device.api.ui.TouchEvent%29)  as [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2556517/peter-strange) suggested, or you can override [`navigationClick`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#navigationClick%28int,%20int%29)  and [`navigationUnclick`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#navigationUnclick%28int,%20int%29)  in your `MainScreen` class. Since you need to do it in every button, I'd rather subclass ButtonField to enable a custom click/unclick listener, thus allowing to reuse the class in other screens.

The timer is just a regular [`Timer`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/java/util/Timer.html)  where you schedule a [`TimerTask`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Comment: Good answer, just wanted to add that within the two seconds, the Hover event will be generated and will probably do what I think it normally does for a Button Field - display the menu.  So you will probably need to suppress this.

Comment: @PeterStrange now we have a circular reference between our answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way of doing this for non touch screen phones.

This is possible to do on touch screen phones  by overriding touchEvent() for the Field.  Look at detecting touchEvent.Click and TouchEvent.Unclick and/or TouchGesture.Hover - in fact Hover is what I think you will hit.

Assuming it is Hover, then you can get an estimate by obtaining the Hover count, or alternatively, use Click to get a start time and subtract when you get the Hover to see if in fact it has been over two seconds.

However I have two concerns:

a) This is not very BlackBerry like - pressing and holding is not something that BlackBerry users do very often.  So is this really a good User Experience?

b) If the field already has some touch capability, then you will probably impact on that processing, so you may have to be very careful about what you process (returning true) and what you pass on to super.touchEvent().

**Update**

Note the other answer which suggests using navigationClick/Unclick for non touch phones.  I had not thought of that, and haven't tested it, but it seems like a good option.  Might even work on touch screen phones too rather than using touchEvent - but watch out for Hover being driven.